# Failed to query the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'

Tags: python, java, android, android-studio, gradle

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to query the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
> Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\Users\any user\Documents\Desktop\Chaquopy 9.1\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@7424ad41) before task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
12 actionable tasks: 12 up-to-date

Comment: Try doing a clean rebuild with the menu item Build > Rebuild Project. If that doesn't work, please click the "Run with --stacktrace" link, and edit your question to include the stack trace.

Comment: It would also be useful to include the `dependencies` section of your top-level build.gradle file, showing the version numbers of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` and `com.chaquo.python:gradle`.

Comment: It's a question about Android development, but there is a Python tag, interesting 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an AGP related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19252

Updating AGP up to 4.2.2 or higher will probably solve this issue.